# Model relation works fine everywhere else but I get a RelationNotFoundException when it comes to broadcasting

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

Model relationship works fine in the controller and the API tests are happy but the moment I try to broadcast it, I get a RelationNotFoundException.

I have two models here, Message and ExtraMessage, a controller, MessageController, and an event MessageSent. They have a One-to-one relationship.

Postman returns the results just fine and my automated tests work fine other than the fact that I mocked out the events with Event::fake() which I think contributed to this one slipping through.

Once it actually hit the test server with people using it, the MessageSent specifically event is not firing at all and checking the logs, I get the offending message:

```
local.ERROR: Call to undefined relationship [extra_message] on model [App\Message]. {
"exception":
"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException(code: 0): 
Call to undefined relationship [extra_message] on model [App\\Message]. 
at /path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/RelationNotFoundException.php:34)
```

Original code below. I tried adding `use App\ExtraMessage;` in the MessageSent event and tried type-hinting Message in the constructor of the event too with the same results.

Message

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Message extends Model
{
    public  $table='messages'
    public function extra_message()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\ExtraMessage');
    }
    public function table1()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Table1::class);
    }
    public function table2()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Table2','foreign_key');
    }
}
```

ExtraMessage

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class ExtraMessage extends Model
{
    public  $table='extra_message';
    protected $fillable = ['column1','column2','message_id'];
    public function extra_message(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Message');
    }
}
```

Controller

```
use App\Message;
use App\ExtraMessage;
use App\Events\MessageSent;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Notifications\ReceivedMessage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use App\Jobs\PushNotificationQueue;
class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public function sendMessage{
        //snip
        $message = Message::create(['my_params'=> $values]);
        $message->extra_message()->create(['my_params1'=> $values1]);
        $message_details = $message->load('table1')->load(['table2' => 'closure'])->load('extra_message');
        //snip
        broadcast(new MyEvent($message_details))->toOthers();
        //snip
        return response()->json(['param1' => $data, 'message' => $message_details])
    }
}
```

Event

```
use App\Message;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializeModels;
    public $message;

    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('channel');

    }
}
```

Stack Trace

```
[2019-11-12 17:01:41] local.ERROR: Call to undefined relationship [extra_message] on model [App\message]. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException(code: 0): Call to undefined relationship [extra_message] on model [App\\message]. at path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/RelationNotFoundException.php:34)
[stacktrace]
#0 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(588): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException::make(Object(App\\message), 'extra_message')
#1 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php(90): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\{closure}()
#2 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(590): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\Relation::noConstraints(Object(Closure))
#3 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(558): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->getRelation('extra_message')
#4 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(538): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->eagerLoadRelation(Array, 'extra_message', Object(Closure))
#5 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(491): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->eagerLoadRelations(Array)
#6 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers.php(102): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->load(Array)
#7 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers.php(57): App\\Events\\MessageSent->restoreModel(Object(Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier))
#8 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/SerializesModels.php(45): App\\Events\\MessageSent->getRestoredPropertyValue(Object(Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier))
#9 [internal function]: App\\Events\\MessageSent->__wakeup()
#10 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(171): unserialize('O:38:\"Illuminat...')
#11 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(203): Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler->failed(Array, Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException))
#12 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(182): Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\Job->failed(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException))
#13 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(462): Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\Job->fail(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException))
#14 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(449): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->failJob(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException))
#15 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(379): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->markJobAsFailedIfWillExceedMaxAttempts('database', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob), 1, Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException))
#16 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(352): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->handleJobException('database', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions), Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException))
#17 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(294): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->process('database', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#18 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(129): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob), 'database', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#19 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(112): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->daemon('database', 'default', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#20 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(96): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default')
#21 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->handle()
#22 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(32): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#23 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(520): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#24 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(90): value(Object(Closure))
#25 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(34): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#26 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(591): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#27 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(202): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#28 path/to/project/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#29 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(189): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#30 path/to/project/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(934): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#31 path/to/project/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#32 path/to/project/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#33 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(90): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#34 path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(131): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#35 path/to/project/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#36 {main}
"}
```

Only real difference I noticed was the other relations are using belongsTo which is fine for the scenarios they are used in. I'm not sure how that breaks the relation once it hits broadcast() as everything else related to it is working as expected.

Comment: The full stack trace to see which line it exactly fails on?

Comment: @mrhn Added the offending stack trace as an edit.

Comment: Can you add a ```Log::info($values1)``` after that line ```$message->extra_message()->create(['my_params1'=> $values1]);``` and show us the result. Maybe you break the association with a ```message_id``` value equal to something. You could also remove the ```->load('extra_message')``` because you already got it into $message when you created the extra message.

Comment: Well, it's odd. After trying to "properly" load the extra_message again, the error isn't coming up again. It may be related to the refactoring work to eliminate repetitive code I did which may have somehow fixed it in the process. Only real change with the logic otherwise was changing to camel case. Thanks for the effort anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel and PHP the standard is camelCase, so if you rename your relation like so, it should work.

```
public function extraMessage()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\ExtraMessage');
}
```

Comment: did you change it both places?

Comment: Yes I did. Ended up creating and storing the model manually in the database and set up a janky, if thoroughly documented, kludge to get the feature working while we figure out on the side why this is still failing if we do it "properly" and only with broadcasts.